# Javascript confirm() not working in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript

I am running a chrome extension that has an input from the user in a prompt(), this will then run through a few functions and should ultimately run a confirm().

However, when I am doing this everything is working fine, but I am then getting the following on the confirm():

*Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function*

This is only happening once I click on the Chrome Extension, before I click on it confirm() works correctly :/

```
function resetPassword(id, name, email) {
    var confirm = confirm("Please confirm the Password rest of '" + name + "' (" + email + ")");
    if (confirm == true) {
        /* Checks the user and marks them as deactivated */
       var password = sforce.connection.resetPassword(id);
    } else alert("Password Reset Cancelled!");
}
```

I am VERY confused here... I have only been using .js for a few months so I am baffled!

Answer (score 1):

Change you code to e.g.:

```
var c = confirm(...);
if (c) {
    ...
```

Your local variable is hiding ([shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373278/variable-shadowing-in-javascript)) the function because it has the same name.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem today with an eval statement I was using in my script.  Not Salesforce related, but I figured it's worth mentioning anyhow.

When I called confirm from the window object, it started working for me.  I believe that eval was creating a virtualized script and running my code there.

Chrome might behave the same way in its extensions environments, so

```
window.confirm('your message');
```

might be worth a shot.

Comment: You do not need a bracket on the else here, it doesn't read well but it compiles and runs perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't work any way until I did this:

```
function resetPassword(id, name, email) {
       if (userConfirm("Password Reset", name, email)) {
        /* Checks the user and marks them as deactivated */
       var password = sforce.connection.resetPassword(id);
       window.location = "https://" + window.location.host + "/" + id + "?noredirect=1";
    } else alert("Password Reset Cancelled!");
}

function userConfirm(type, name, email){
    return confirm("Please confirm the " + type + " of '" + name + "' (" + email + ")");
}
```

It's really weird :/